# Capstone for Python not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, gentoo

I'm unable to get [Capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html) for Python to work.

I have attempted to install capstone both using pip and compiling and installing from source. Both are successful, no errors, but neither works. I've tried this on Gentoo and Ubuntu.

On Gentoo stable:

```
>>> import capstone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/capstone/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from capstone import Cs, CsError, cs_disasm_quick, cs_disasm_lite, cs_version, cs_support, version_bind, debug, CS_API_MAJOR, CS_API_MINOR, CS_ARCH_ARM, CS_ARCH_ARM64, CS_ARCH_MIPS, CS_ARCH_X86, CS_ARCH_PPC, CS_ARCH_ALL, CS_MODE_LITTLE_ENDIAN, CS_MODE_ARM, CS_MODE_THUMB, CS_OPT_SYNTAX, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_DEFAULT, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_INTEL, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_ATT, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_NOREGNAME, CS_OPT_DETAIL, CS_OPT_ON, CS_OPT_OFF, CS_MODE_16, CS_MODE_32, CS_MODE_64, CS_MODE_BIG_ENDIAN, CS_MODE_MICRO, CS_MODE_N64, CS_SUPPORT_DIET
ImportError: cannot import name Cs
>>>
```

Contents of the file /usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/capstone/**init**.py:

```
from capstone import Cs, CsError, cs_disasm_quick, cs_disasm_lite, cs_version, cs_support, version_bind, debug, CS_API_MAJOR, CS_API_MINOR, CS_ARCH_ARM, CS_ARCH_ARM64, CS_ARCH_MIPS, CS_ARCH_X86, CS_ARCH_PPC, CS_ARCH_ALL, CS_MODE_LITTLE_ENDIAN, CS_MODE_ARM, CS_MODE_THUMB, CS_OPT_SYNTAX, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_DEFAULT, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_INTEL, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_ATT, CS_OPT_SYNTAX_NOREGNAME, CS_OPT_DETAIL, CS_OPT_ON, CS_OPT_OFF, CS_MODE_16, CS_MODE_32, CS_MODE_64, CS_MODE_BIG_ENDIAN, CS_MODE_MICRO, CS_MODE_N64, CS_SUPPORT_DIET
```

This seems a bit strange to me.

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
>>> import capstone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/capstone/__init__.py", line 184, in <module>
    raise ImportError("ERROR: fail to load the dynamic library.")
ImportError: ERROR: fail to load the dynamic library.
>>>
```

Comment: Look at the example you provided.  Try `from capstone import *`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved doing:

```
from capstone import *
```

Answer (score -2):

Try remove it then re-install:

```
apt-get install python-capstone
```